# DAX DEFINE won't register or turn blue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this code where I'm trying to get the max monthly value of all time for each tenant. Problem is, the DEFINE stays black in the code and when I run it, it pulls the subsequent line to it so it says "DEFINEVAR MAUbyMONTH"

```
DEFINE
VAR MAUbyMONTH = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        MonthlyActiveUsers[year],
        MonthlyActiveUsers[Month],
        MonthlyActiveUsers[TenantId],
        "MYMAU",
        SUMX(MonthlyActiveUsers,MonthlyActiveUsers[MAU])
        )
        
EVALUATE

VAR PeakMAU = CALCULATE(GROUPBY(MAUbyMONTH ,MAUbyMONTH[TenantId], "PEAKMAU",MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(),[MYMAU])),FILTER(ALL(MAUbyMONTH),  MAUbyMONTH[TenantId] = StudentEnrollmentTop[Tenant ID])))

Return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(PeakMAU[PEAKMAU]),
    FILTER(ALL(PeakMAU), PeakMAU[TenantId] = StudentEnrollmentTop[Tenant ID]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to define the column name by prefacing the code with
`ColumnName =`